# Subrequest in WIQL

Tags: tfs, wiql

How can I use subrequest in WIQL TFS?
I need something like this

```sql
SELECT
    [System.Id]
FROM workitems
WHERE [System.Id] IN (
    SELECT
        [System.Id]
    FROM workitems
    WHERE [System.Title] == 'Example' 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is not available at present. There has already been a related user voice here:

> **TFS: Queries based on results of other queries**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2300378-tfs-queries-based-on-results-of-other-queries

As a workaround to execute sub queries or joins using the TFS query execution engine you will have to use the method  RunLinkQuery().

For a detail sample you could take a look at this blog: [Using the TFS API to display results of a Hierarchical Work Item Query](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/using-the-tfs-api-to-display-results-of-a-hierarchical-work-item-query)

Comment: I asked not about TFS API but about WIQL in web-interface of TFS.The main point is how to make this:
```sql
WHERE [System.Id] IN (--Other query results)
```

Comment: @axtrace Sorry for the misunderstanding, have updated my reply. This is not available to directly use WIQL in web portal from query, there is a related user voice. Hope it helps.